# How to add and item to an Array using Vue JS?

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I'm using VUE JS and for some reason I don't get the new item displayed on the view. if I use the push method, nothing happens. If I use this.$set('productos',producto) the item is displayed, but when I tried to push another item to the array, the previous item is deleted.

```
new Vue({


    el: '#ticket',

    data:{
        newCodigo:{
            codigo: '',
        },

        productos:[],

    },



    computed:{
        errors: function(){
            for(var key in this.newCodigo){
                if(! this.newCodigo[key])
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    },


    methods:{

        addProducto: function(){
            var codigo = this.newCodigo;
            this.$http.post('/api/addProducto', codigo).success(function(producto){

                this.productos.push(producto);
                //this.$set('productos',producto);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I'm able to retrieve the data from the DB, but it's not displayed on the view.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div id="ticket">
        <form action="POST" v-on:submit.prevent="addProducto">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" > 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Codigo">
                    Escanea:
                    <span class="error" v-if="! newCodigo.codigo">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo" class="form-control" v-model="newCodigo.codigo">
            </div>
        </form>
        <article v-for="producto in productos" :data="productos">

            <h3>@{{producto.descripcion}}</h3>

            <h3>@{{producto.precio}}</h3>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the callback function of your ajax call, `this` does not point to the vm instance. Just change it to:

```
this.$http.post('/api/addProducto', codigo).success(function (producto) {
    this.productos.push(producto);
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried with bind and still not showing on <article v-for="producto in productos" :data="productos">

            <h3>@{{producto.descripcion}}</h3>

            <h3>@{{producto.precio}}</h3>
        </article>